# WPF: Manipulating DataGrid binding in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

Lets consider three classes as following:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string genome { set; get; }
}
public class Car
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public int model { set; get; }
    public int horsePower { set; get; }
}
public class Tree
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public int age { set; get; }
}
```

And collection of each type as following:

```
    ObservableCollection<Animal> animals { set; get; }
    ObservableCollection<Car> cars { set; get; }
    ObservableCollection<Tree> trees { set; get; }
```

We have a `ComboBox` which it's items are `animals`, `cars`, and `trees`. Based on user's selection each of these collections will be displayed in a `DataGrid`. However, since data types are different, it would not be possible to define a proper binding of column in advance, and bindings has to be changed with respect to `ComboBox` selection. Do you have any suggestions on how to address this scenario ?

Assumptions:

- We're in MVVM pattern.
- We don't wanna have one `DataGrid` for each type (summing up to 3 `DataGrid`s in total).
- We're not allowed to modify the models.

Comment: Dear @Hamed as you can see from any binding example in code behind you need to point a `DependencyProperty` for an UI element and according to the MVVM approach we separate model and view as you know. So your question's title is `"Manipulating DataGrid binding in ViewModel"` is not a good idea. But I had tried to give you an idea for your dynamicity goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want multiple datagrids, I would go with a single datagrid with all the columns for all the object types. At runtime you'll hide the columns not related to the current type.
BTW It's not any different than having multiple datagrids and hide those not related to the current type.

Comment: I like the idea of one universal datagrid with all columns. But still I can't figure out how you could have multi-bindings or converters that are opposite of each other. For instance, a converter that converts `animal.name` is different from the converter that modifies `tree.name`. In your proposal, I should have also different `name` columns which will work but not a clean and elegant solution.

Comment: If the only difference between the variuos Name columns will be the ValueConverter, I think you can switch it at runtime using GetBindingExpression / SetBinding. If there are other differences (validation, layout, etc) I would go with 3 different columns (they would be different things despite having the same name).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataTemplate` for each class and then change the template at runtime with a `DataTemplateSelector` like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is interesting, but do you think a DataTemplate can help with itemSource too ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to bind data dynamically to DataGrid ,we can use type **dynamic**.

create a property as follows

```
public ObservableCollection<dynamic> SampleListData
    {
        get { return _sampleListData; }
        set { _sampleListData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleListData"); }
    }
```

-in XAML bind combobox selected value to a property

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbStatus" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="67,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="opAnimal" Content="Animal"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="opCar" Content="Car"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="opTree" Content="Tree"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

-so on change of combobox value ,you can bind itemsource based on the selected value.

```
public string selectedStatus
    {
        get { return _selectedStatus; }
        set 
        {
            _selectedStatus = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("selectedStatus");
            if (selectedStatus == "Tree")
            {
                SampleListData = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();

                SampleListData.Add(new Tree { name = "Mohan", age = 25 });
                SampleListData.Add(new Tree { name = "Tangella", age = 28 });
            }
            if (selectedStatus == "Car")
            {
                SampleListData = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();

                SampleListData.Add(new Car { name = "Mohan", horsePower=68,model = 1 });
                SampleListData.Add(new Car { name = "Mohan", horsePower = 72, model = 1 });
            }
            if (selectedStatus == "Animal")
            {
                SampleListData = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();

                SampleListData.Add(new Animal { name = "Tiger", genome="H" });
                SampleListData.Add(new Animal { name = "Lion", genome="FG" });
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps to you.